# Concise way of repeating multiple tests with same test data in JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I have many tests - in different test classes - that should run using the same sets of sample data. Here is an example test method.

```
@Test
public void testTracerErrorPerPixel() {
    // Iterate over all sample images
    // ** This is the line I want to refactor out **
    for (Image image : SampleImages.values()) {

        // Do some tests on those images

        Assert.assertTrue("Tracer error in " + image + " too large after tracing, error per pixel is " + someValue, someValue);
    }
}

@Test
public void testTracerCorrectPixelPercent() {
    // Iterate over all sample images
    // ** This is the line I want to refactor out **
    for (Image image : SampleImages.values()) {

        // Do some different tests on those images

        Assert.assertTrue("Correct pixel percent in " + image + " too low after tracing, % correct " + someValue, someValue);
    }
}
```

Is there a standard more concise way of doing this? Having `for (Image image : SampleImages.values()) {` feels like the wrong way of doing this.

Using another framework such as TestNG would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using the `Parameterized` runner for this matter. More information is found [in the junit docs](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests).

In your case you can write

```java
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParameterTest {

    @Parameters
    public static Iterable<Object[]> data() {
        // extract to some class for readability and reuse
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] { 
                { new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB) }, 
                { new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB) } 
        });
    }

    private Image image;

    public ParameterTest(Image aImage) {
        image = aImage;
    }

    @Test
    public void testTracerErrorPerPixel() {
        // Do some tests on those images
        System.out.println(image);
    }

    @Test
    public void testTracerCorrectPixelPercent() {
        // Do some different tests on those images
        System.out.println(image);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By swapping to TestNG, I was able to make use of DataProviders to clean this up.

This is the example from above, changed to use DataProviders.

```
@Test(
    dataProvider = "images",
    dataProviderClass = Images.class
)
public void testTracerErrorPerPixel(Image image) {
    // Do some tests on those images

    Assert.assertTrue("Tracer error too large after tracing, error per pixel is " + someValue, someValue);
}

@Test(
    dataProvider = "images",
    dataProviderClass = Images.class
)
public void testTracerCorrectPixelPercent(Image image) {
    // Do some different tests on those images

    Assert.assertTrue("Correct pixel percent too low after tracing, % correct " + someValue, someValue);
}
```

A DataProvider was also added in Images.class.

```
@DataProvider(
        name = "images",
        parallel = true
)
public static Object[][] createImages() {
    // Make the array of images
}
```

I'll accept this answer tomorrow unless someone else provides an answer that works without swapping to TestNG.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Personally, I don't think this makes your tests neater.

Comment: @JamesB The annotations do seem a little verbose, it's longer than the loop. However, instead of one test which passes or fails, it's a test per image. This makes more sense to me, as you will get a pass/fail for every image instead of only seeing the first that made the test fail. Also, you don't have to include the name of the image in each assert's message in the test, which I have forgotten to do before.

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor this test as follows:

```
@Test
public void testVectorError() {
    // Iterate over all sample images
    for (Image image : SampleImages.values()) {

        PixelComparer comparer = compare(image);

        // Ensure that traced image is close to original image
        Assert.assertTrue("", comparer.rootMeanSquareErrorPerPixel < 0.01d);
    }
}

private PixelComparer compare(Image image) {

    Pixels original = image.getPixels();

    // Trace image to vector
    Tracer tracer = new Tracer();
    tracer.trace(pixels);

    // Redraw image at same resolution
    Pixels tracedAndRedrawn = tracer.render(original.width, original.height);

    PixelComparer comparer = new PixelComparer();
    comparer.compare(original, tracedAndRedrawn);

    return comparer;
}
```

The compare method could either be an internal method to the test class (as shown) or placed into a test utility class and then re-used by multiple test classes.

I think it is important to apply the DRY principle to tests as well as application code. That is what is important here, not what tool you use (JUnit, TestNG).

Comment: While this is helpful, it doesn't answer the question. I'm concerned about refactoring the `for (Image image : SampleImages.values()) {` which is used in many tests, not improving the design of the API which is being tested. Additionally, the logic of tracing an image and redrawing it is applicable only to that test, and it does not make sense to refactor that out. For example, testPixelComparer may want to .compare(original, original) and ensure that the pixel error is exactly 0, as there should be no difference.

Comment: I've updated the question, it should now be more clear what I meant. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

```
package stackoverflow.q_24932384;

import org.junit.Test;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class CommonJUnitData extends TestCase{
    private boolean areImageEqual= false;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        //Your image code which will set value of areImageEqual value, like:
        areImageEqual = compare.compare(original, tracedAndRedrawn);
    }

    @Test
    public void testTracerError() {
        //Use areImageEqual variable value
    }
}
```